# TypeError: plot_confusion_matrix() got an unexpected keyword argument 'title'

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, matplotlib-animation

```
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
 from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
 from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix
 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
 from sklearn.svm import SVC
 cm_plot_labels = ['Normal', 'Tuberculosis']
 cm_plot_title =['Confusion Matrix']
 plot_confusion_matrix(cm, cm_plot_labels, title='Confusion Matrix')
```

TypeError: plot_confusion_matrix() got an unexpected keyword argument 'title'
please tell me how to resolve the error

Comment: `plot_confusion_matrix` has no `title` argument. remove it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this a caused by a typo / not reproducible

Answer (score 1):

You can add a title when using [`plot_confusion_matrix`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix.html) as follows:

```
clf = SVC(random_state=0)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
cm = plot_confusion_matrix(clf, X_test, y_test)
cm.ax_.set_title('Confusion Matrix')
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix.html) there is no such keyword argument as *title*. This is what causes this error. Try to remove it.